# Call java class from other project in soapui

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have 2 soapui projects. In 1st I have groovy script with my java class and all methods and I need to call it in 2nd project from script. I try this:

```
Test tst = new Test()
log.info tst.getConnection()
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: it will not work you have to import jar of that 2 project or make a client of 2nd project's web service in your first project

Comment: shall I post it as a answer???1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work you have to import jar of that 2 project or make a web service client of 2nd project's web service in your first project.